# Problem with HTMLInputElement in jquery

Tags: jquery

This code is giving me objecxt.HTMLInputElement in jquery

```
var values = $('input[name=delete]:checked').each(function(i, selected) {
                                                return $(selected).attr('value');
                                                }).get().join(",");
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
$('input[name="delete"]:checked').map(function(){ return this.value }).get().join(',')
```